# Cross-origin error in canvas html5 kineticJS using path file://

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs, todataurl

I want to create image from my canvas, I'm using kineticjs, but I get error: "Kinetic warning: Unable to get data URL. Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported." I suppose, that it's caused by cross-origin error. In canvas I use localy saved images and address path starts with "file://..". Is there any solution how to create image without apache installing? Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at any of the EXISTING answers on this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Tainted+canvases+may+not+be+exported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local hard drive is deemed to be "other domain" by browsers and will taint Canvas.

That's a good thing!  You don't want malicious code to get at stuff on your personal drive.

Some workarounds:

- Install a web server on your computer.
- Put your image(s) and all files associated with your web app on the desktop (this may/may not help depending on where you got the images to begin with).
- Temporarily host your images on a site that allows anonymous cross-origin access to your images.